# ¿Como conectar una maquina virtual en azure de ubuntu server a monog db compass?

Tags: mongodb, azure

Tengo una máquina virtual con ubuntu server en la nube de azure, estoy implementando una pagina web y la he trabajado con mongo db compass pero no se como hacer para usar mongo db compass en ubuntu server en la nube de azure.

Ya esta subido y desarrollado el proyecto pero necesito conectarlo a mongo db compass

Answer (score 0):

este problema lo tuve hace tiempo y no tengo manera de hacerlo de nuevo para ser mas concreto, a si que te hablo de memoria.

En primer lugar, has de instalar mongodb-compass en la maquina de ubuntu `sudo apt-get install mongodb-compass`. Esto hazlo en la maquina virtual

Despues habre Mongodb Compass en tu maquina local y dale al boton "Connect" y ahi tendras una opcion que se llama "SRV Connection String Only". Ahi tendras que poner la cadena conexion SRV de Mongodb que la tienes en la pagina de inicio de Azure (Una cadena SRV de mongo tiene este estilo: `mongodb+srv://<usuario>:<pass>@<direccion>/<baseDeDatos>`. Cuando lo tengas todo le das a "Connect"

Siento no haber sido muy concreto pero aun asi no dudo que esa informacion la tengas en internet mas concreta si no te funciona lo que te explico aqui. Un saludo